# Galaxy S5 lock screen

Tags: lock-screens

[image: e]A series of letters and numbers have shown up beneath the date on the lock screen of my Galaxy S5.  What are they and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: Wait what? This is supposed to be here since you setup the some of the secure lock probably pin, so it's there to enter the pin. How do you unlock the phone if you don't know the use of buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This field is intended to display the owner informations: name, phone or email on the lock screen. Perfect if you have lost or misplaced your device. So I would think that you entered those random letters by mistake.

To enable, disable or change, this go to **Settings – My device (or **Sound and display** section and then tap Lock screen) – Lock screen – Lock screen widgets.** Then at the bottom press **Owner information**. Here you can enter any information you want, such as your name or email address.

*As a note, if your owner info length is more than 33 characters then your owner info will be displayed as a running text on lock screen.*

Comment: Glad that I helped. Could you, please,  accept this answer to help others in the need find it ?